# Can you program an ESP32 with an Arduino?

Tags: esp32, uart, programmer

I've done it with an ESP-8266 but can't find any articles on how to do it with an ESP-32. I'm working with an ESP-32 on my own PCB, not a dev board. I exposed:

- 3V3
- GND
- EN
- TX
- RX
- IO0

I'm pretty sure I can use a standalone programmer but I was expecting to be able to do it with an Arduino. Is that possible? ...if it's super difficult to do like setting up a toolchain and all that I'd rather just spend $10 and get a programmer.

Comment: it is the same as with esp8266. there is no programmer.